# autoload.php failed opening, vendor file not present in Apache

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, apache2, laragon

I've seen this question be asked before but I am having trouble finding one that fixes my problem - I am currently working with (and new to) Laravel Blade and Apache2. I have set up a project on our development server which is returning a 500 error on the staging website and the site-error.log shows the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/WEBSITE-NAME/htdocs/public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/WEBSITE-NAME/htdocs/public/index.php on line 34
```

Line 34 of index.php is:

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

The path to the vendor folder is C:\laragon\www\WEBSITE-NAME\vendor which contains the autoload.php file.

I have tried `composer install` a few times with no change.

However the `vendor` folder isn't showing on the Apache2 server in the `htdocs` for the project. `.gitignore` was automatically updated with `/vendor` so I am not sure if this is the reason why it is not on the server, but other working projects have `/vendor` in their `.gitignore` and /vendor is present in their files on Apache.

Apologies if I haven't explained this well - any guidance would be appreciated, thanks so much!

Comment: If location is `www\WEBSITE-NAME\vendor`, then you would need to go *two* levels up from `/var/www/WEBSITE-NAME/htdocs/public/`. You're only using one parent directory call in `__DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking a look - this didn't help unfortunately. The project runs fine locally with Laragon, but doesn't seem to be pulling everything to the staging server, such as the vendor folder which contains autoload.php is not present. Would you have any idea why this may be? Thanks again!

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Haven't worked a lot with deployment and Git. Best I can do is wish you good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved by manually installing composer into the project folder on the server :)

Comment: Although that worked, running `composer install` in the project directory (`/var/www/WEBSITE-NAME/htdocs`) should have installed the required dependencies and resolved the problem. What was the result from running the command? Any errors or did it start running through the install process?

Comment: No errors, it went straight into the installation process on the server. One thing I am unsure of is if I will have to `composer update` on the server any time I push any changes that involve composer?